# Changing protection level of newly created object?

Tags: c#, wpf, object, string.format

Alright, so I have luck of running into a lot of basic problems. I can't figure a way around this particular issue.

This piece of code needs to access "_Player.Name" property of object created in "MainWindow" class.

Edit: Putting up the whole code this time. Here's the Code_Behind where the string is.

```
public class Code_Behind
{

    private static string _Name = "Default";
    public class Player
    {
        public void setName(string name) //Ignore this part, was trying to find a work around here
        {
            _Name = name;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
    //contentControl is used to store Content properties
    //UI elements are bound to Content properties to efficiently change their Content
    public class contentControl : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        public void setEvent(string Event)
        {
            textBoxContent = Event;
        }
        public void addEvent(string Event)
        {
            textBoxContent +="\n" + Event;
        }
        public class Events
        {
            public string EV001 = String.Format("\"Greetings {0}. What can I do for you today?\"", window.PlayerName);
        }
}
```

And here is the MainWindow one:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Code_Behind.contentControl cC = new Code_Behind.contentControl();
    Code_Behind.contentControl.Events Events = new Code_Behind.contentControl.Events();
    Code_Behind.Player _Player = new Code_Behind.Player();
    public string GetPlayerName()
    {
        return _Player.Name;
    }
    public static string _name = "null";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = cC;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: ```public Code_Behind.Player _Player = new Code_Behind.Player();``` ?

Comment: `EV001` is not a good member name. Consider something more readable and self-describing.

Comment: You can't change the protection level of an object, because objects don't have protection levels. Fields and variables do. tym32167 has one answer; mybirthname has a better one. Mine is best: `public String PlayerName { get { return _Player.Name; } }`

Comment: @tym32167 No, sadly that just ends up in Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainWindow._Player'

Comment: @Zephylir you can make it ```public static ...```, but not sure that this is exactly wnat you need in this case.

Comment: @Zephylir You should put `this.DataContext = cC;` after `InitializeComponent()`, not before. Nothing should happen before `InitializeComponent()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying write something like a viewmodel: You've got a player, he has a name, and there's a collection of strings that you think of as "events". I don't understand what the "events" are meant to be, but I implemented my best guess at what I think you seem to be trying to do.

As for this:

```
    public class Events
    {
        public string EV001 = String.Format("\"Greetings {0}. What can I do for you today?\"", window.PlayerName);
    }
```

I guess you created an instance of `MainWindow` somewhere, and called it `window`, but it's defined someplace where it's "out of scope" for that line of code. By analogy, you can't see anything that's behind the next hill, only stuff that's in the valley you're standing in. That's roughly (very roughly, sorry) kind of what scope is about.

But let's move on to my guess at what you're trying to do. This builds, runs, and works. Any questions at all, fire away.

ViewModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Player
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Player Property
        private PlayerViewModel _player = default(PlayerViewModel);
        public PlayerViewModel Player
        {
            get { return _player; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _player)
                {
                    _player = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Player));
                    //  Change the player for all the existing events.
                    foreach (var e in Events)
                    {
                        e.Player = Player;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Player Property

        private ObservableCollection<Event> _events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
        public ObservableCollection<Event> Events
        {
            get { return _events; }
            private set
            {
                if (value != _events)
                {
                    _events = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Events));
                }
            }
        }

        #region Event Methods
        //  This is a BIG guess as to what you're trying to do.
        public void AddGreeting()
        {
            //  Player is "in scope" because Player is a property of this class. 
            if (Player == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Player is null. You can't greet a player who's not there.");
            }
            Events.Add(new Event("\"Greetings {0}. What can I do for you today?\"", Player));
        }
        #endregion Event Methods
    }

    public class Employee : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region DisplayLtdOccupationId Property
        private bool _displayLtdOccupationId = default(bool);
        public bool DisplayLtdOccupationId
        {
            get { return _displayLtdOccupationId; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _displayLtdOccupationId)
                {
                    _displayLtdOccupationId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayLtdOccupationId));
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion DisplayLtdOccupationId Property
    }

    public class Event : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Event(String format, PlayerViewModel player)
        {
            _format = format;
            Player = player;
        }
        private String _format = "";

        public String Message
        {
            get { return String.Format(_format, Player.Name); }
        }

        #region Player Property
        private PlayerViewModel _player = default(PlayerViewModel);
        public PlayerViewModel Player
        {
            get { return _player; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _player)
                {
                    _player = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Player));
                    //  When player changes, his name changes, so that 
                    //  means the value of Message will change. 
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Message));
                    if (_player != null)
                    {
                        _player.PropertyChanged += _player_PropertyChanged;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void _player_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(PlayerViewModel.Name):
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Message));
                    break;
            }
        }
        #endregion Player Property
    }

    public class PlayerViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private String _name = default(String);
        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Player
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();

            ViewModel.Player = new PlayerViewModel() { Name = "Ivan the Terrible" };
        }

        //  Just here as a convenience, and to make sure we don't give the DataContext
        //  the wrong kind of viewmodel. 
        public MainViewModel ViewModel
        {
            set { DataContext = value; }
            get { return DataContext as MainViewModel; }
        }

        private void Greeting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel.AddGreeting();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window 
    x:Class="Player.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Player"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <WrapPanel>
                <Button x:Name="Greeting" Content="Greeting" Click="Greeting_Click" />
                <Label>Name: </Label>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Player.Name}" Width="120" />
            </WrapPanel>
            <ListBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding Events}"
                DisplayMemberPath="Message"
                >
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for wasting your time with this, which is literally a waste of time. I honestly have a brain soup, trying to get the whole idea of this code. But I guess it would be easier to tell you my intention with the code, so you'd have easier time explaining this to me. What I am trying to do, is create an 'Event' which uses player's name instead of {0}. The event itself is displayed in a Textbox which displays a specific event with a press of a button. My issue is that both Player class and 'contentControl' class, exist inside same class, and can't access object instances from MainWindow class.

Comment: ...if it didn't make my intention clear make sure to mention so, as I just barely fit all of that. I literally reached 0 characters left on that period at the end

Comment: @Zephylir You're having the problem you're having because the code is organized completely wrong. It's like you're telling me the problem is your car won't go straight up a cliff. That's not really the problem. The problem is that you should be on the road that goes *around* the mountain.

Comment: @Zephylir My version is pretty simple -- simpler than yours, I think. The properties in the viewmodel have a lot of stuff, but it's all just paint-by-numbers filler for INotifyPropertyChanged. This thing you've got with all the classes defined in other classes, that doesn't make sense. I think you haven't gotten a handle yet on what classes are in C# and how they're used. I can't think of a quicker way to explain than to show you how to do it right. I know the learning curve's a PITA, no way around that.

Comment: Yeah well I get that, but I just can't think of a way of finding a better way to do it. I could create a 'third-party method' to get the name and all, but the problem is this: Does changing object instance of "Player", actually changes the class it was created from? If no, then I need to find a way to get the value from Player object, because it's Name value is changed using "Player.Name = inputBox.Text;" To be honest I think I've composed the question completely the wrong way.

Comment: @Zephylir Your code creates all these weird difficult problems you wouldn't need to worry about if you did it properly. When you change the player's name, do you expect all the Event text to change?

Comment: Well yeah, I know it is a mess in total, because I haven't got a grip on this that well. The thing is, I want the text to partially change, say depending on the Player's name property and gender property for example. But what would be efficient way of dealing with it? I need to somehow store those values, while making them available to both MainWindow class and one they are located in. Actually I think with some rework of it from ground-up I could make it work better...

Comment: Okay yeah, I have a more fitting question. How do I store 'event strings' and 'player properties', in an efficient way, while making it possible for them to be both changed, and accessed by MainWindow class? I am so clueless it's shameful, I went through some basics of C#, but nothing there would help me that much with my intentions here

Comment: @Zephylir In that case, what you're looking for is templating in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

```
public string GetPlayerName()
{
    return _Player.Name
}
```

Create a method in your `MainWindow` class. After that you call this method.

```
public string EV001 = String.Format("\"Greetings {0}. What can I do for you today?\"", 
                       window.GetPlayerName());
```

You can do it with property too if you want.

```
public string PlayerName
{
    get { return _Player.Name; };
}
```

Comment: It'd be a great solution, but for some reason it fires off CS0120 when I use 'MainWindow.GetPlayerName()'

Comment: @Zephylir you should create MainWindow object.

Comment: @Zephylir Do you think that mysterious reason might be illuminated at all by reading the text of the error message?

Comment: @mybirthname I think he needs to get to the existing `MainWindow` instance, not create a new one.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes if he has already existing instance of the window, take it. But in his code I don't see it. I suppose he never created it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah it would, but it doesn't. That error fires off when you try to refer to something that is not an object, but in this particular case I am trying to refer object, which still fires off the error. Currently this fires it off `EV001 = String.Format("\"Greetings {0}. What can I do for you today?\"", window.GetPlayerName);` Edit: And yes I created instance of window inside the class where 'EV001' string is, using this form 'MainWindow window = new MainWindow();'

Comment: @mybirthname This is almost certainly WPF, in which case `((MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow)` is a reference to the existing `MainWindow` instance.

Comment: @Zephylir I can't guess anything from microscopic fragments of code with no context. If you share enough code for me to reproduce the issue, I can help you with it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well I could toss up the whole code, but it'd be a bit too long. Should I add it to the question's content then?

Comment: @Zephylir The whole class would be good, even if it's a bit much. I would infinitely rather wade through too much code than have to keep going back to you and asking for more details.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Well I trimmed it up so it showed the parts that actually produced errors. To make it easier to read. I honestly feel bad that I ask so many stupid questions, but I am just stuck on them as if it was a steel wall

Comment: @Zephylir Perfect. Thank you. Don't sweat the stupid questions, nobody's born knowing this stuff .

Answer (score 1):

The bigger problem you have here is not about accessibility, but not understanding the difference between a class and an object.

MainWindow is a class. It does not represent any specific window. Think of a class like a recipe to create objects. If you had a chocolate chip cookie recipe, you don't eat the recipe, you eat a specific cookie or cookies baked following that recipe.

Your other class first needs to know which specific window you are trying to get the player name from. It needs a reference to a particular MainWindow object.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `set` of `Name` to be `private`, but still allow the outside world to read the property with the get.

```
public string Name { get; private set; } = "Default";
```

This should give you the functionallity desired without the need to create a new `GetName()` method.